# How can i intersect a line with it´s rotated counterpart?

Tags: plotting, geometry

So, i'm trying to intersect an infinite line with a line, this is my code for now, i have been using Region Intersection, but it seems it does not work with this case i have:

```
s1 = {-41, 14}
s2 = {-40.5, 14.5}

v1 = {-24.3, 0.4}
v2 = {-16.86, 1.34}
v3 = {-21.46, 7.43}

md = Midpoint[{v3, v1}]

prism = {v1, v2, v3, v1}

a = Rotate[InfiniteLine[{s1, md}], -Pi/35, s1]

Show[ListLinePlot[{prism, {s1, md}}, PlotRange -> All], 
 Graphics[Rotate[InfiniteLine[{s1, md}], Pi/35, s1], Frame -> True], 
 Graphics[Rotate[InfiniteLine[{s1, md}], -Pi/35, s1], Frame -> True]]
RegionIntersection[a, InfiniteLine[{v1, v3}]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
a =TransformedRegion[InfiniteLine[{s1, md}],RotationTransform[ -Pi/35, s1]]
p = RegionIntersection[a, InfiniteLine[{v1, v3}]]
Graphics[{a, InfiniteLine[{v1, v3}], Red, p}, Axes -> True,PlotRange -> {-10, 10}]
```

[image]